# How to use ffmpeg to extract frames from video and read as a list of images in python in memory without writing files

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pipe

At my application server, I have a stream of Webm chunks coming from browsers that users record live videos. I want to analyze each frame simultaneously. So I used python to create a generator yielding the Webm file binaries to feed into ffmpeg. I use the command `python convert.py | ffmpeg -i pipe: -r 1 output%3d.jpg` to create a set of frames files. (The convert.py is just the generator to yield binary webm data for ffmpeg).

My question is that how can I make the ffmpeg output to a new pipe that in python I can read as a list of images directly?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
python convert.py | ffmpeg -i pipe: -r 1 -c:v mjpeg -f image2pipe pipe: | python example.py
```

Comment: Hi llogan, thanks for your reply. But what should be in the read.py ?

Comment: @yiy That's up to you. It was just an example to show how to pipe to and from ffmpeg which is what I thought you wanted to do.